# Insert if exists only works if there are records in table

Tags: sql, database, jdbc, derby

I'm using the following query to insert a record into a table only if it does not exist:

```
INSERT INTO tblExample (exampleColumn)
  SELECT 'test' FROM tblExample
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tblExample where exampleColumn = 'test');
```

It works fine as long as there is at least 1 record in the table. If there are no records, it will not insert the record into the table.

Can anyone see what is wrong with my query?

Thanks!

Comment: As expected, if there are no rows in your table, the select will return 0 rows!

Comment: Thanks @jarlh. Can you suggest an improvement so that it achieves my objective?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Do you have one-row table available?

Comment: I'm using Apache Derby.

Comment: does it work as expected if you have 2 rows in `tblExample`?

Comment: No, I've just tried it and it doesn't. It adds the new record twice!

Comment: Adding 'distinct' fixes that. But the main problem is that I cannot add a record if it doesn't exist where there are no records in the table.

Comment: i'd try something like: `insert into tblExample select * from ( values 'test') t WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tblExample where exampleColumn = 'test');`

Answer (score 1):

Tested with Derby 10.12

```
INSERT INTO tblExample (exampleColumn)
SELECT *
from (values ('test')) as x(col)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM tblExample t
                  where t.exampleColumn = x.col);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
INSERT INTO tblExample (exampleColumn)
SELECT  Value FROM (  SELECT 'test' Value) T1
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tblExample where exampleColumn = 'test')
```

Or you can use this

```
INSERT INTO tblExample (exampleColumn)
SELECT  Value FROM (  SELECT 'test' Value) T1
    LEFT JOIN tblExample ON exampleColumn = Value
WHERE exampleColumn IS NULL
```

Comment: Hi @Abdul Rasheed , I like your first answer, but it looks like JDBC / Apache Derby doesn't support your alias syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Query is :

```
INSERT INTO user (id, name, date)
SELECT 23,test,DATE('2013-02-12')
FROM  contact
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM user WHERE id = 23 )
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help. I have found that the best way to add a record if it doesn't already exist (even when there are no records in the table) is by using the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO tblExample(exampleColumn) 
(SELECT 'test' FROM tblExample WHERE exampleColumn='test' HAVING COUNT(*)=0);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your first query **"SELECT 'test' FROM tblExample"** will return 0 rows if there is not record in a table.

**Use bellow code.**

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tblExample where exampleColumn='test')
    insert into tblExample(exampleColumn) values  ('test')
```

Comment: Is that part of a larger statement? Starting an sql statement with 'if not' doesn't seem like valid syntax

Comment: yes, you can have "EXISTS" and "NOT EXISTS" in sql statement.

Comment: This is not a valid statement (in derby):   ERROR 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "IF" at line 1, column 1.